# How to add title to svg rectangle using pure javascript (not d3.js)?

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I made changes to the code.Are they in the right manner, because tooltip or title are still not showing up.

```
var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href",    "mydefs.svg#hello");

var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
title.textContent = data[i].status;//JSON Object

svg.appendChild(rect);
svg.appendChild(text); 

//Use and Title added

svg.appendChild(use);
svg.appendChild(title);

document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: I don't see where you are adding `use` to the document.  If it isn't being added, then I can quite understand the tooltip not appearing.

Comment: @Luke Is this the same way of adding "use", as title/tooltip does not appear?

Comment: Now you're adding the title to the whole SVG element rather than just your `use` element.  Are you sure your `data[i].status` JSON object exists?  Try replacing it with a static text string such as `"test"` to see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is very confusing because you don't say what purpose of the `<use>` is. Plus what is `text`?

If you want to add a `<title>` to a `<rect>` element, all you have to do is this:

```
var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
title.textContent = data[i].status;//JSON Object
rect.appendChild(title);
```

Comment: Thank u. As it is a part of code, I used text for showing text on svg rect element.